# How to limit user to only put in octal number in Java or loop until they do?

Tags: java, octal

So I am trying to make the user give me an octal number or loop until they do.  I cannot figure it out.  Please help!  Thanks!

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
boolean valid = false;
while (!valid) //first loop unitl uers inputs correct value
{ // starts the main loop
    System.out.print("\n \nInput an octal number: ");
    String octatl = keyboard.next();
    if((ocatal.contains("8") || ocatal.contains("9"))) // invalid input tester
    {// starts second loop for user to input correct value
        System.out.print("Incorrect octal input...re-enter number.");
        System.out.print("\nInput an octal number: ");
        String octatl = keyboard.next();
    }// ends loop
    valid = true; // end user input loop
}
```

Comment: Testing if every character is 0..7 is certainly simpler than testing that `octatl` contains none of the million of unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

You might simplify your logic by doing the following (pseudo-code):

```
 boolean isValid = false;
 System.out.Println("describe what the input should be like")
 String line;
 while (!isValid) {
    line = keyboard.next();
    if (line only contains 012345678) { valid = true;}
    else {System.out.println("reenter");}
 }
 work with line
```

By the way you want to make sure that only the numbers 0-7 are entered .. you don't want to accept a line like    octal  which does not contain an 8 or 9

Comment: You accidentally included 8, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ... Try it and let me know.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean valid = false;
        String octatl = "";
        System.out.print("\n \nInput an octal number: ");

        while ((octatl = keyboard.next())!=null) //first loop unitl uers inputs correct value
        { // starts the main loop


            if((octatl.contains("8") || octatl.contains("9"))) // invalid input tester
            {// starts second loop for user to input correct value
                System.out.print("Incorrect octal input...re-enter number.");
                System.out.print("\nInput an octal number: ");
                continue;
            }// ends loop
         break;
        }
```